# Action of symmetry on field operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, symmetry, representation-theory

I am working in the context of a Wightman quantum field theory and have the following definition of a symmetry:

> 'A symmetry is a bijective map $T:\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$ of the rays such that the transition probabilities are invariant, i.e. if $T[u] = [u'], T[v] = [v']$, then
> $\frac{(u',v')}{||u'||||v'||} = \frac{(u,v)}{||u||||v||}$ for all $u\in [u]$, etc.'

Now I want to know the canonical way to let such a symmetry transformation act on the fields of the theory viewed as operator valued distributions. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You haven't specified which symmetry you're interested in, so how can we know how it acts on the field operators?  Obviously that depends highly on the symmetry and the QFT model.

Comment: Boundedness does not matter, I do not understand the problem.

Comment: You are right, I did not formulate the question well. My problem is that for many results in the theory of symmetries in QFT one uses the action of symmetry generators on the fields of the theory (e.g. Coleman Mandula), and I do not see how they are in one-to-one correspondence to the symmetries defined via the states.

Comment: I think you should be more specific what you are looking for. But *perhaps* what you are asking about is answered in Chapter 5 of "The Quantum Theory of Fields" by Weinberg. In that chapter he connects the unitary representations of the Poincaré groups on the Hilbert space of states and the Lorentz group representations acting on fields. But again that is something specific about relativistic symmetry and may not be what you want, since you don't specify which symmetry you are interested in.

Comment: @user1620696 The point is that I need to know that answer for general symmetries. I know that a symmetry of a physical system is a ray transformation of its states, but I keep reading that symmetries are maps of the fields of the theory. I have no idea how those two definitions go together.